# Launch APN Android settings activity from a program

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch the Android APN settings menu from within a program. I do not know the Class name. Please help.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Now, in regards to your question, it is very confusing, people here will want to help you but will not know how, so please consider adding more information to your question, like code samples, what have you tried so far, etc.
Here is a helpfull guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS, 0));

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. But i used startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS)